# Как добавить флаг -std=c++17 или -std=gnu++17

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, netbeans, include

Пишу программу на C++ в Linux в среде NetBeansIDE.
Хочу использовать  `#include <fillesystem>`, чтобы ее использовать нужно добавить флаг `-std=c++17` или `-std=gnu++17`. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80548/discussion-on-question-by------stdc17--stdgnu).